# Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm implemented via Priority Queues and an adjacency matrix represented graph

Tags: java, graph, dijkstra

My adjacency matrix looks like this, where non-zero weights denote edges.

[0, 2, 0, 0, 3]

[2, 0, 2, 4, 0]

[0, 2, 0, 3, 0]

[0, 4, 3, 0, 1]

[3, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Here's my attempt, would appreciate a code review.

```
private static class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {
    private int source;
    private int destination;
    private int weight;

    public Edge(int source, int destination, int weight) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return source + "---" + weight + "---" + destination;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Edge other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.weight, other.weight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof WeightedGraphMatrix.Edge) {
            return equals((WeightedGraphMatrix.Edge)other);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean equals(Edge other) {
        return other.destination == this.destination;
    }

    @Override // Uses only the destination to calculate hash for the purposes of maintaining the visited hashset.
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        int hashMultiplikator = 79;
        return hash * hashMultiplikator * destination;
    }
}

public static void printDijkstras(int [][] graph, int source) {
    // Prints shortest distances to all nodes from the source.
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Dijkstras(graph, source)));
}

public static int[] Dijkstras(int [][] graph, int source) {
    // Ideally should check matrix's validity to be square and symmetric but haven't done here since its pretty straightforward.

    int [] nodesVisited = new int [graph.length];
    Queue<Edge> edgeQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    int [] shortestDistance = new int[graph.length];
    Arrays.fill(shortestDistance, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    // Start with the source vertex.
    int currentNode = source;
    shortestDistance[0] = 0;
    nodesVisited[0] = 1;

    do {
        for (int col = 0; col<graph[currentNode].length; col++) {
            // Take all edges from this node. Skip self & 0-weight edges
            if (col == currentNode || graph[currentNode][col] == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            edgeQueue.add(new Edge(currentNode, col, graph[currentNode][col]));

            // Update distance for this destination if better than existing.
            if (shortestDistance[col] > shortestDistance[currentNode] + graph[currentNode][col]) 
            {
                shortestDistance[col] = shortestDistance[currentNode] + graph[currentNode][col];
            }
        }

        //find cheapest edge to a not already visited destination.
        Edge edge = edgeQueue.remove();
        while (nodesVisited[edge.destination] == 1) {
            if (edgeQueue.isEmpty()) {
                return shortestDistance;
            }
            edge = edgeQueue.remove();
        }

        // Now that you've reached this edge as a destination, record it.
        currentNode = edge.destination;
        nodesVisited[edge.destination] = 1;
    } while (!edgeQueue.isEmpty());

    return edgesVisited;
}
```

Would also appreciate some help figuring out the runtime for my implementation and if it can be improved. For a Graph with V vertices and E edges, my outer loop runs V times, and the inner loop which iterates over each vertex's edges runs V times as well, leading to a runtime of V^2. The PQ remove call takes O(logE) time, so I think it ends up being O(V^2 + logE) which doesn't sound very efficient.